# How session and cookie works?

Tags: php, session, cookies

When i create a session variable where is saved username and password, how does it works internally? Same question about regular cookies where information is saved. Which type of information are included in coookie and session? What is the difference between them?

Comment: @bobby, see the log of the question. It didn't look like that at first

Comment: Because if he had spent half as much time researching these questions as he did registering and posting on this site he would have had his answers a thousand times over.

Comment: NSD, the original poster clearly doesn't have enough knowledge or context to sift through the myriad answers they're going to find on the subject. That's part of what Stack Overflow is for

Comment: @marcgg, never knew SO had question logs. good thinking.

Answer (score 12):

The best article on sessions and cookies I ever found is

http://shiflett.org/articles/the-truth-about-sessions

Comment: Awesome article. Thank you.

Comment: Please include necessary paragraphs that concern the user question.

Comment: Web archive link: http://web.archive.org/web/20170425074935/http://shiflett.org/articles/the-truth-about-sessions

Answer (score 4):

To sum it up a cookie is a file on the client's computer. You can store whatever in it (objects, text...). A session object can be stored in a cookie in the same way you can store some text. Keep in mind that session != cookie because sometimes you can store a session object in the database.

But still, you'll have to read up some documentation, I think.

Seen on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie):

> In computing, a cookie (also tracking
>   cookie, browser cookie, and HTTP
>   cookie) is a small piece of text
>   stored on a user's computer by a web
>   browser. A cookie consists of one or
>   more name-value pairs containing bits
>   of information such as user
>   preferences, shopping cart contents,
>   the identifier for a server-based
>   session, or other data used by
>   websites.
>
> It is sent as an HTTP header by a web
>   server to a web browser and then sent
>   back unchanged by the browser each
>   time it accesses that server. A cookie
>   can be used for authenticating,
>   session tracking (state maintenance),
>   and remembering specific information
>   about users, such as site preferences
>   or the contents of their electronic
>   shopping carts. The term "cookie" is
>   derived from "magic cookie", a
>   well-known concept in UNIX computing
>   which inspired both the idea and the
>   name of browser cookies. Some
>   alternatives to cookies exist; each
>   has its own uses, advantages, and
>   drawbacks.
>
> Being simple pieces of text, cookies
>   are not executable. They are neither
>   spyware or viruses, although cookies
>   from certain sites are detected by
>   many anti-spyware products because
>   they can allow users to be tracked
>   when they visit various sites.
>
> Most modern browsers allow users to
>   decide whether to accept cookies, and
>   the time frame to keep them, but
>   rejecting cookies makes some websites
>   unusable. For example, shopping carts
>   or login systems implemented using
>   cookies do not work if cookies are
>   disabled.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, session data is stored on the server, and it uses a tracking cookie to attach a user with the data.  Cookies on the other hand are set directly in the user's browser.

One key difference:  Session variables generally can't be seen by the end user, but cookies can(with the right browser plugin)

Also, if you have multiple front-end web servers, cookies will be sent to all front end servers, but session data is not shared between them without extra work.