# Why do $_SESSION and $_COOKIE behave differently?

Tags: php, session, cookies

I've done some testing with $_SESSION and $_COOKIE because I they weren't working as I expected. I'd like to know why these lines of code behave differently.

```
$_SESSION[1] = 'foo';          // Does not work because of the integer
$_COOKIE[1] = 'bar';           // Works

$_SESSION['foo bar'] = 'foo';   // Works with the space
$_COOKIE['foo bar'] = 'bar';    // Does not work
```

I would have thought $_SESSION and $_COOKIE would be identical, other than being server side vs. client side. Are there any other differences between the two?

Comment: It's just one difference, but it's an important one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answers on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622947/how-session-and-cookie-works) address some of the issues involved, but the short answer is that there are different restrictions depending on whether it's a session or a cookie. Sessions are restricted space-wise by different php.ini settings, cookies don't allow spaces in keys, etc.

Comment: The relevant part of this is **cookies don't allow spaces in [names]** (and thus keys in $COOKIES don't). This is just how HTTP cookies are defined. There are also some browser quirks dealing with cookies... but alas, outside the scope of PHP and covered elsewhere.