# What is the relation between cookies and session?

Tags: php, session, cookies, browser, authentication

Is it possible to delete `$_COOKIE`(cookies) from browser where `$_SESSION`(sessions) also destroys. 
Where both are stored. How both are interrelated to each other ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How session and cookie works?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622947/how-session-and-cookie-works)

Comment: You have session cookies, that last while your browser tab/window is open, and "regular" cookies that are stored in your device until you clean the cookies or they expire.

Answer (score 0):

session uses the cookies to store its values. but session can also work without cookies if cookies are disabled in the web browser.every time when user enter into a website a Unique session id is generated for that user. session either store the session id in cookies or that session id is propagated in the URL.